# Easy Variable Question in Visual Studio 2010 Express Please help

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a unit converter and what I have is one button and two textboxes. What I want the button when pressed to do is convert whatever is entered to the other side (what isnt entered)

ALSO! Another thing that would be great would be how do I implement a drop down menu so I dont need to do so many buttons and fields? Thanks <3

TEXTBOX BUTTON TEXTBOX2 (say TEXTBOX is Fahrenheit and TEXTBOX2 is Celsius) I enter in the Fahrenheit and leave TEXTBOX2 and hit the button I should get the Celsius now. Simple enough right?

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace UnitConverter
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (boxc.Text=="")
                boxc.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 /5) +32;
        }


        }
    }
```

Sorry when it comes to numbers and strings I always get thrown for a loop :\ Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you press the button?

Comment: Tell us what's wrong with what you have.  Compile error? Run-time exception? Incorrect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
boxc.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 /5) +32;
```

With

```
boxc.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 /5) +32);
```

Comment: Tried both ways, very similar but both work thanks again :D Now I know of two ways.

Comment: Mark it as answer then if you find it helpful :D

Comment: Darn I wish I could mark them all but since you asked ill mark it heh. My first post. If you could tell me how to make a drop down menu to select different items that would be awesome. If not ill try and make do with radio buttons.

Comment: You could use menu strip control, explore it budy.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. All I know is what our professor taught us and that's just the "Toolbox" components.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
boxc.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32;
```

You're trying to put a double back into the textbox; you need to convert the result back to a string:

```
boxc.Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32).ToString();
```

Also, you mixed up the formulas; I believe you're trying to convert from Fahrenheit (the value in boxf) to Celsius (the value in boxc), but you're using the formula to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

Comment: First comment I tried worked, looks like others would too. Thanks a ton everyone :) Minus the fact that I had F and C backwards lol. 55F doesnt = 131C o.O *smacks head* 2am.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double c ;
try{
 c= double.Parse(boxf.Text);
}catch{
MessageBox.Show("Error!Invalid Data");
return;
}

    if (boxc.Text.Trim().length==0)
                    boxc.Text =( (c * 9 /5) +32).ToString();
```

Comment: TryParse would be a better choice than Parse.

Comment: I changed the formula around but also like this way too, takes up less space (converts it in the same box though so I would need another box and button for the other conversion)and also allows users to mess up and give a warning when they enter letters or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
boxc.Text = ((Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 / 5) + 32).ToString();

instead of
boxc.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(boxf.Text) * 9 /5) +32;